# Как принять данные в state от двух пользователей бота Aiogram 3

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Cтолкнулся с проблемой. Задача - принять по одному фото от двух пользователей, сделать запись в БД с этими пользователями и фотографиями.
Когда открываю state получаю фото от первого пользователя, а далее нужно как то открыть state для другого пользователя и принять фотографию для него в этой же машине состояний. Как это можно реализовать?
Пробовал создавать отдельные экземпляры класса FSMContext, однако не смог их обрабатывать.
**ВАЖНО: Aiogram 3.x!**

Comment: Пользователи в одном чате или в разных?

Comment: Два разных пользователя обращаются к одному боту

Comment: Насколько знаю в аиограм состояния работают в рамках одного чата, то есть не получится 2м разным пользователям из разных чатов пользоваться одним состоянием. Сделайте свой костыль со словарем, не знаю, как у вас это реализовано, но создайте условно булевую переменную, которая будет задавать состояние, создайте проверку, если тру, то ждет нужные данные, эти данные вносите в словарь по user_id, и проверяйте, если ключей 2 штуки, то записывайте данные в БД, а словарь очищайте. Ну и кнопка для выхода, которая будет менять режим с тру на фолс. - Первое, что в голову пришло.